# input textbox hidden behind keyboard on android Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mobile

I have a mobile web page of the following format:

header - logo etc - absolute positioned

content - scrollable, absolute positioned

footer, 40px absolute positioned

The content area has multiple input boxes. On Chrome on Android, 
tapping on an input box at the bottom of the page causes the input
to not be in view when the soft keyboard pops up. The page
does scroll to try and move the box up, but not enough to actually
be visible. It ends up hiding behind the footer.

Any idea how to fix this? This occurs only on Chrome-Android. Safari on iOS
and IE on Windows Phone and other mobile browsers work just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was hoping for a CSS only solutions, but I don't think there is one. Gaunt Face's answer is a good way of doing it. Unfortunately in my case, this would require a few changes and has the possibility of breaking automation among other things (since the url has #targets added to it).

I solved this by changing the position type in 2 click handlers.

I have a click handler for any input/textarea field. In that click handler, I change the position style of the form container div to be static. Note this will push the footer to the bottom if the container field has a scrollbar. This, in my case is not a problem as when the keyboard pops up, only a couple of fields are visible. The user cannot visibly see any difference.

I have a second handler for when the user clicks out of an input field - page click handler - where I restore the the position type to absolute, making the page appear just as it was before.

This has one unintended consequence - The scroll position is lost. I fixed this by getting the offset of the input field and calling scrollTop on the parent div with that offset, thus restoring the position.

I've seen a few questions about this, but did not find an answer. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is not a complete answer:if anyone has number type fields, android shows a "next" button instead of Go. This means that click won't be triggered. Instead, you can check for focus event, add your custom "keyboard-up" class to the body, then on the blur event set a timeout at 50 ms that checks if the focused element is the body. If it is, it means that the user has either clicked out of the inputs or closed the keyboard in any other way. So you can remove "keyboard-up" from the body.

Comment: there is a CSS solution, take a look to my post ;)

Answer (score 8):

There are a few ways you could solve this, the most obvious solution is to use javascript to set a hash on the URL.

You can see an example of that here: http://jsbin.com/emumeb/24/quiet Code: http://jsbin.com/emumeb/24/edit

For a slightly more complex example, if you have a fixed header and footer, you might want to use targets to change the appearance of the page when a hash is set.

Depending on your layout you might need to get a little more creative, you could set a class on the body for focused vs non focused state and change the UI accordingly, but it starts to get tricky to maintain a good experience across mobile, desktop etc

Heres an example http://jsbin.com/emumeb/30/quiet Code: http://jsbin.com/emumeb/30/edit

Obviously this is something chrome should deal with itself (similar to the UX iOS has), so I've raised a bug against Chrome - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=270018&can=4&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified.

Comment: This is a nice way of doing it. Thank you. Unfortunately in the code that I'm working on, this would have to be done in a bunch of places, automation will have to be updated and so on. I'm going to write what I did as an answer for anyone else who might come across this.

Comment: @Gaunt Face Link to the bug for us to star? :)

Comment: `<div class="input-div">
   <textarea id="blend_name" class="textArea1 " name="message" placeholder="Type your name here" style="font-size: 14px; white-space: pre-wrap; line-height: 20px;"></textarea>
</div>`

Same issue, It is coming over the text area
Here I have fixed header and footer, how can I fix this.

Comment: @GauntFace I have similar problem but my input fields are in popup form, do you know any turnaround for this.

Comment: Not working at all. (Without digging into your code implementation) The hashing prevents focus on inputs making it pretty much useless.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not smart like you guys,

So I took a ruler and measured the size of my cell phone screen.
2nd Then measured the size of the keyboard

I noticed that the keyboard occupied 38% of the screen.

So I put a div in the footer and called it affectionately frog.

and I used this code:

```
 $('body').on('focus', 'input, textarea', function(event) {
        var altura = $(window).height();
        var scrollp = parseInt(parseInt(altura)/100*38);
        $("#divSapo").css("height",scrollp + "px");
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
```

Comment: we need more people with rulers. 

Comment: Screen sizes vary

Answer (score 7):

Changing from **absolute** positioning to **fixed** positioning should fix the issue.  Absolute positions the element with respect to the initial page-size during page load (adding a keyboard shrinks the visible page).  Fixed positions the element with respect to the current page-size, keeping the element above the keyboard.

```
#myElement {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and this only works on a few phones and not even always on them too.

Answer (score 5):

I found a CSS solution that works very well.

You can do a css query for a window screen of 300px height o less, that is the mostly screen height of phones with the software keyboard displayed. It works very fast and very well. For example

```
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {

    #myinputtext{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 50px;

    }
}
```

Comment: These are pretty dangerous assumptions! You cannot assume from viewport size which device you have. Also tablets have keyboards and those have the same viewport size as desktops.

Comment: @Andy Yes, my post just show another option that can help in some cases. And it could happen this issue in tablets, but it is less frequent, their keyboard usually takes up less screen percentage.

That are disadvantages, but the advantages are the the speed and compatibility of the method.

Answer (score 3):

I used `scrollIntoView` to solve this issue.

```
$(document).on('focus', selector, function() {
    document.querySelector(selector).scrollIntoView();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can use the codes as follow:

```
$('body').on('focusin', 'input, textarea', function(event) {
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > -1 && ...){
   var scroll = $(this).offset();
   window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
 }
});
```

Though, the bug should be solved now.

Comment: that didn't work for me. Even with the two lines in your if(..), the window doesn't scroll up above the keyboard.