# Bootstrap 3 - How to maximize input width inside navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-input

Right now I have a navigation bar that looks like:
http://bootply.com/78239

I want to maximize the width of the "search" text-input, without creating line-breaks (i.e., that the "Clear" link will be tight with the "About" link).

I only have basic experience with css and web-design. I read something about "`overflow: hidden`" tricks, but I don't understand how to use it when there are more elements to the right of the targeted element.

Thanks

---

EDIT:

A partial solution can be to set the width "manually" for each case, like in http://bootply.com/78247 :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #searchbar > .navbar-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  #searchbar > .navbar-form {
    width: 205px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #searchbar > .navbar-form {
    width: 425px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #searchbar > .navbar-form {
    width: 625px;
  }
}
```

but this solution will not work when the menu's texts are "dynamic" (for example, contain "Hello username").

I suppose it is not a big issue if you assume that there is a limit on the menu's texts' widths - it's just annoying to calculate/test those widths manually.
I'm just curious to know if there's a neat way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For Bootstrap version 3.2 and up you should also set the `display:table;` for the `input-group` and set the width to `1%`  for the `input-group-addon`.

```
<div style="display:table;" class="input-group">
            <span style="width: 1%;" class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Here" name="search" style="" class="form-control">
          </div>
```

Demo Bootstrap version 3.2+: http://www.bootply.com/t7O3HSGlbc

--

If you allow changing the position of your navbar elements? I don't understand "without creating line-breaks (i.e., that the "Clear" link will be tight with the "About" link)." Try this: http://bootply.com/78374.

What i did:

- Drop the float left of the form (by dropping the navbar-left class)
- Give other navbar elements a right float (the navbar-right class)
- Set display of the form-group to inline (`style="display:inline"`)
- Change the position of the elements (the right floated first)

Related question:

- [Expand div to max width when float:left is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set)

**html**:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Project</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="searchbar">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li id="userPage">
          <a href="#@userpage"><i class="icon-user"></i> My Page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#logout" data-prevent="">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" title="Start a new search">Clear</a></li>
      </ul>



     <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fully understand why changing the position of the elements solves the problem, but it works! I guess the "display:inline;" applies to previous elements (i.e. to put them in the same line) and not to following ones - am I right?

Comment: To see what happens add a colored background to your form. Float element take "all" available space. Changing the position reserve space before calculating the available space for your form. See: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ The form-group get a inline-block display from boostrap by default. This prevent the input from taking 100% of the available space again, see: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: The one thing I see as a problem is it gets hidden by the keyboard when you click to search in there on an Android device. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Wahou thanks. Even though I consider having a decent understanding of css and bootstrap now, I could not get my way out of this by myself...

Comment: any way of achieving this with **Bootstrap 3.2**?

Comment: @jasonflaherty does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110852/input-textbox-hidden-behind-keyboard-on-android-chrome fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Two things worked for me here. Adding Orens media queries, and also adding a `display: inline` to that searchbar form group:

```
<li id="searchbar">
          <form id="search_form" class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-input-group " role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">All <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input name="search_input" type="text" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Search for items or shops" autofocus="autofocus">
              </div>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </button>
          </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
```

With the css:

```
#search_form > .input-group > .form-group {
  display: inline;
}
```