# Fitting text field in the middle of navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to fill a textbox in the middle portion of the navbar as shown in the figure.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

I looked at [Bootstrap 3 - How to maximize input width inside navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552714/bootstrap-3-how-to-maximize-input-width-inside-navbar) but that input field is not automatically resizing when the window is resized.

Actually that was not his requirement, I just posted to show that I tried that method. I need the auto resizing also.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Shells <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Jobs <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">History <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#console">Help</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Account</li>
                        <li><a href="#console">Edit Profile</a></li>
                        <li id="logout"><a href="#console">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You ***need*** to add your HTML.

Comment: Added HTML as per MackieeE