# Searchbar width in navbar bootstrap + offset

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I would like to raise the width of my input type text in my boostrap navbar, and keep it responsive, but don't know how to do that . Seem to be completely impossible
Here is the sample of the code
http://www.bootply.com/klx0LnIMF9

I used to watched this post:
[Bootstrap 3 - How to maximize input width inside navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552714/bootstrap-3-how-to-maximize-input-width-inside-navbar)

In fact the code given by Bass Jobsen is  the exact same code , somehow  it 's workinb for bootstrap 3.0.0 but not for bootstrap 3.2.0

If anyone can help, it could be great,

Thanks in advance

Anselme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it's not the same solution you have in that link, just a quick fix I've made for this question and may need a few adjustments to fit your needs, but take a look at your [forked example](http://www.bootply.com/0EpsyodWad)

Only one tiny change in your HTML (that inline style you don't need at all and it's more annoying than useful) and a bit of CSS as follows:

```
.navbar-form {
    padding:0;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50% !important;
    border: 0px none;
}
.form-group {
    width:100%;
}
.input-group-addon:first-child {
    border-right: 0px none;
    width: 30px !important;
}
.navbar-form .input-group {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As you'll probably notice, I just get rid of the float and replace elements properties by inline. Once done, I have the ability to better play with responsive widths. You'll probably notice the !important definitions. You may or may not need them (Bootstrap has a few !important declarations, so be sure to test), but basically I'm applying this to ALL sizes, so you may probably want to change that `width: 50% !important;` in **.navbar-form** to `width: 100% !important;` for 768px and under, but anyways, here you have the tools to play around and adjust as you like

Comment: thanks fabio! It really helped me; I used to know a bit of css but when it come to responsive and % in it, i'm just lost... Thanks again