# Bootstrap Navbar with dynamic search box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to make the above code behave well on displays > 768px and < 768px. Right now is working fine for resolutions below 768px, but I can't make it work for resolutions above that.

That's the what I'm trying to do:

Resolution above 768px - Full page (search box with 100% remaining width):
[image]

Resolution below 768px (only search box visible):
[image]

Code:

```css
.navbar .navbar-form {
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.clear {
  width: 1%;
  display: table-column;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {

  .navbar .navbar-form {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-form .input-group {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-form .form-control {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/">Title</a>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."/>
                        <span class="clear hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span>
                        <span class="input-group-btn hidden-xs">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/webpage1">Webpage 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/webpage2">Webpage 2</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but this seems to be working fine..

Comment: If you make it full page (> 768px) then the search bar isn't 100% width (at least not on chrome). Question is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, you have yourself a nasty little problem here. It took me a while, but I think I've gotten you a solution together.

First, you need to do the following:

- Add `display: inline` to your `form-group`
- Add `display: table` to your `input-group`
- Add `width: 1%` to your `input-group-btn`

These changes are from this issue here (what you want, but keeps the search bar inside the collapse menu) - [Bootstrap 3 - How to maximize input width inside navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552714/bootstrap-3-how-to-maximize-input-width-inside-navbar/18562948#18562948)

The next changes you need to make are for when you are above the 768px breakpoint, otherwise it will mess up your collapse menu.

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .container-fluid {
        display: flex;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        flex: 1;
    }
}
```

Lastly, you need to remove `navbar-right` from your `navbar-form`.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chadh89/DTcHh/18940/) - An embedded snippet is also included.

```css
.navbar .navbar-form {
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.clear {
  width: 1%;
  display: table-column;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {

  .navbar .navbar-form {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-form .input-group {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-form .form-control {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .container-fluid {
        display: flex;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        flex: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/">Title</a>
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="form-group" style="display: inline">
                    <div class="input-group" style="display: table">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."/>
                        <span class="clear hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span>
                        <span class="input-group-btn hidden-xs" style="width: 1%">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/webpage1">Webpage 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/webpage2">Webpage 2</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```