# Add autocomplete to Wide Searchbar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, navbar

I have been spending the past few days in what I thought was a very simple task: Have an autocomplete feature for a search bar in Bootstrap 3. What I am trying to achieve is to integrate it into the Bootstrap 3 design without breaking the layout.

I have looked into ways to use both twitter-typeahead.js and bootstrap3-typeahead..

Part of the difficulty may be that I wanted to have a large searchbox as part of the 'navbar-fixed' element, I used this solution / workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552714/bootstrap-3-how-to-maximize-input-width-inside-navbar

The challenge that I have is that whenever I include the typeahead class, the style of the seach bar changes back to a different css style, breaking the layout. I then attempted the same using autocomplete.js.

The actual level of autocomplete functionality is very trivial at this point, I only want to match the exact string so I do not care about the exact implementation - my only requirement is: (1) Typeahead/autocomplete and (2) Keep the wide search bar in a Bootstrap navbar searchbar

Anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/wamh2h5h/show/

Comment: Thank you Amal, this fixed the issue! Can you explain why the issue occurs and how it's in the fiddle fixes this? Again, many thanks!

Comment: Hi,col. slade.it works fine if you added typeahead.js only.But when adding typeahead.bundle.js and bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js the searchbox gets broken.see this https://plnkr.co/edit/nnDcPgWAmrizkbTP5iBp?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
var indicator=["aaa","abc","def","rrr","yyyt"];
function searchautocomplete(itemclass,data){
      $(itemclass).typeahead({
                  hint: true,
                  highlight: true,
                  source:data,
                  limit:data.length
      });
}
searchautocomplete(".form-control",indicator);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wamh2h5h/show/)