# Keyboard shows up after textbbox clicked ,then the mobile view scrolls wrong

Tags: c#, android, model-view-controller, scroll, keyboard

The websites are MVC C#  with kendo UI. It is no problem with the computer and ios phone(iphone) devices.But on Android, if the user clicked the website's textbox, the keyboard shows up and the websites scrolls, the user can not see the focus of the textbox. On the computer and ios phone, the user clicks the textbox,the view stands still and does not scroll. So I use the following CSS code on javascript of cshtml to fix:

```
    @media screen and  (max-width: 580px) and (max-height: 350px)and (min-height: 200px){
   html {
      display:block!important;
      overflow:hidden!important;
    }      
}
```

If the textbox has clicked, the keyboard shows up and makes view smaller. While the view is smaller, the view can't scroll and it reveals the same correct view with a computer device and ios phone. But, it is only correct on some Android devices.So how can I use CSS to make the view of the website does not scroll when the keyboard shows up on Android phone device? Thanks!
The following is success case in ios phone device:

[1.website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT5W9.jpg)

[2.select event and open event window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnQZp.jpg)

[3.Scroll down to the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl1v2.jpg)

[4.scroll down the textbox and focus the the end part of the text in textbox ,then keyboard shows up.It's no problem on this ios phone case ,but on android phone case,it will scroll up to wrong place.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsl4p.jpg)

Comment: Did you test in mobile chrome browser or others ?

Comment: In mobile chrome brower.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot?

Comment: I can't .Should I expland more about question? Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110852/input-textbox-hidden-behind-keyboard-on-android-chrome

Comment: I add pic to the probem discribe,it may make the problem more clear.